# Windows XP detects new IDE controller and IDE channels on startup and keep new hardware wizard popping up on every boot. How to resolve?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

Every time I boot up my Windows XP box it says it detected new hardware an IDE controller and several IDE channels and every time the new hardware wizard pops up.

I'm 100% sure I'm not installed any new hardware in my computer. Device manager does not show the question mark on any devices. Every device is working properly.

The device it found is an Intel IDE controller (8086 vendor id) and (27DF device id.)

I tried to find driver for it. Apparently many sites claim to have it but they either want to charge me for it or the downloaded package does not contain the driver I need.

How can I prevent my box from asking for drivers every time. Is it safe to disable those devices it complains about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe caused by some (accidental) change in BIOS settings, because some onboard disk controllers can operate in more than one mode (i.e. RAID/non-RAID) and some motherboards may have more than one controller. So, if you familiar with BIOS settings, you may try to play with those are about disk controllers (some changes can make your system unbootable, but it can be fixed by returning settings to previous values).
If not, try to look for drivers on your PC or motherboard vendor's website (you need to know model name), it's absolutely free

Comment: Now I remember. I fiddled with that some month ago. (because I ususally boot into Linux it didn't have problem with this. But XP has.)